# How to use my laptop as a monitor

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, hp

I am trying to use a Jetson Xavier NX Developer Kit, but I don't have a monitor. Is there a way I can use my laptop as a monitor?

My operating system is Ubuntu 18.04 and my laptop is an HP Spectre x360.

Comment: Does your laptop have a video capture card or a video input?

Comment: It has an HDMI port.

Comment: If it has only one it's probably HDMI **out**

Comment: I see. So it's probably not possible?

Comment: Probably not in the way that you would imagine. You'd need to set up something like VNC.  If you use the title of your question as a search term here, some others have asked about this before.

Comment: Have a look at /Settings/Sharing/Screen Sharing. It should not be too hard if both computers run Ubuntu. Use **Remmina** for a remote desktop client.

Comment: @user1551817 Have you found a solution yet that works for you on this interesting question?